# Input matrix row values iteratively into a function

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix which is `100x1` in size. I wish to input each row value of my matrix into a function iteratively. For example, say `L1` represents row 1 of my matrix `L`, `L2` row 2, and so on. Say my function which I seek to input each value of `L` into is denoted `Y`. Therefore I seek to input `L1` into `Y` to Produce `Y1`, `L2` for `Y2` and so on.

I could really do with help on how to implement this in matlab?

accept
Code is as follows:

```
load('logregdata.mat')

%%Data set X is a series of coordinates in two dimensions and t represents class labels. Data set is for a binary classification problem.

u = rand;

[w1,w2] = meshgrid(-5:0.1:5,-5:0.1:5);

w = zeros(2,1);

w_all = zeros(100,2);

%Probabilistic term of logistic classifier prob_t = 1./(1+exp(-[w1(:) w2(:)]*X'));

L = sum(log(prob_t).*repmat(t',numel(w1),1),2);

L= L + sum (log(1-prob_t).*repmat(1-t',numel(w1),1),2);

u = rand;

y = log(L/u);
```

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: Why not change the function so that it can support a vector ?

Comment: The function is simply Y=log(L/u),   where u is a uniformly distributed random number

Comment: Your current code would help. Vectorization is highly dependent on the operations being performed. Is `u` the same for each row of `L`?

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted. It is difficult to ascertain what you're doing wrong without some code to provide context.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have posted the code below

Comment: 1) We can't run this example because we don't have the input data. 2) It seems that a lot of this code is unnecessary for answering your original question (see [mcve]). 3) You don't actually identify what the problem is. What is this doing, and what *should* it be doing. The part of the code you included in the comments, `y = log(L/u)`, looks fine to me. Both `log` and division should work element-wise on `L`.

Answer (score 0):

A 100x1 matrix is just a vector! So you can loop through the entire array like this:

```
for i = 1:100

      do something with Y(L1)

end
```

Comment: I tried the above but it was producing a 100x1 output for y as opposed to a y output for each L input. Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code `u` is just a scalar, so you can use simple element-wise operations:

```
y = log(L./u);
```

which will give you a vector `y` in the same size of `L` such that `y(k) = log(L(k)/u)`